# I need to add a space between the X axis data in heatmap echarts

Tags: heatmap, echarts

I need to add a space between the data on the X axis where in the print there are markings in red I need a margin that doesn't let the data touch, I'm using the heatmap to make a graph with a lot of data and I need this to make it cleare, But I couldn't add.

I already looked in the documentation, I couldn't find a feature that can add this improvement to my graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WC5H.png)

```
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
    '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
    '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
    '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
    '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
    'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
    'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];
// prettier-ignore
const data = [[1, 0, 5], [0, 0, 1]]
    .map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
option = {
  tooltip: {},
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    borderWidth: '10px',
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          margin: 10,
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I can currently think of is to use a [border](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderWidth) for heatmap items.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PTAEAcCcFMBdYJbUgWgQcwHYHsYFgAoAY20wGdZQALbAV0jNAF5QBtQ0T0AcgEYAmAIbcAND17Cx3IaJ4BmSTwAsi7gFZVANkkcu3AOyqAHKoCcq3gAYLE0bs59-4WX2dSnLuW-Xf1b-zyavvq-Rr6mvlaRvM6EALoA3IQgEDDwSKgYOPjEpBSgACaCAJ6MLOwEXDwAyoKw9EXFLgBikAiNLgAqVPRkHSIB3ADq0AWY0H0lXbQT_TwAsqRz3NW0mB3xSQQpUHCIyGhYuNCEJOSURbCCzGysvGKWYmpxYqyPoO-8cXEBAHQAtoJwAAKABmayIiFIoGBCFg0H-AEpQABvAJpeiYNhwhF3F6gHH_N74wmsfhxUAAH0pPBQ3EShAAvoitthwFCsSw0ZVQLBsNgADaIcAALlRjIGPPQbQKYu5VSo0AwVFgYvUlgApHYeZw-aLxJruLoJboAB4AQVNCDIcoCsGK4GgaqIdWg6FwTUlVUugjFNF6Xq4ACNcAVkEN2rAqGqoqbtVUyOABXDzTBfaiApwyDQAO5i2CQGYBE060AALzFVmNgeKlutttL9sdztd7sgnoCPrFjTIgazSZTaYbVSzufzhegfdAJaqFdAVZ5M9AADdrbRBAL5kDh1x_ghMGLHgFAabK0fSy6BURaALBEGBU7eROp7gkJhVTwaG0y6QrgL41wD6gh-3BENA77IABnAhvA2D_DGahatWuhkMgSA2mwATyiOmCCP8j7cAAChCVCgAAwoIkAFFBXBNgRip1IC_ilpwXaFHUghTpwt5BtAAo7iOoDZtgeZPkWLHTlxBLwv81T2g-AkjiGVHhpG0agGoUnQaGyBkYKuBqjmVA4kaElLlUCLgFQghkPWGYSZwhJycUCn2YJVSApA6D7meWlcNmggFCJABCAr0L5mYjgFQU5npAoGTwXlBoIwLvGlDy_GoiKme506RYyxa6D8BCMgkQA):

```js
series: [
    {
        type: 'heatmap',
        itemStyle: {
            borderWidth: 5,
            borderColor: 'white'
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: I had already thought about this solution but it doesn't solve my problem, I only need this margin at the top and bottom of the items